# Sql Server : Select query where the input contains the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, input, where-clause

**Table** `FEES(Name, Amount)`

```
Name    | Amount
================
RCT     | 2,000
Filling | 3,500
Cleanin |   500
```

Input : MRCT on 22

Output : We now need to select the Name, Amount from **FEES** WHERE %Name% LIKE 'MRCT on 22'

    Which means, we need to select the row from **FEES** whose Name is contained in the Input.

**Expected Result**

`(Name, Amount)`

```
Name    | Amount
================
RCT     | 2,000
```

SQL Query needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Amount
FROM FEES a
WHERE 'MRCT on 22' LIKE '%' + a.Name + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Charindex, for this.

```
Declare @name varchar(60) = 'MRCT'
select name, Amount from
Fees where 
CHARINDEX (name , @name,0) > 1
```